# OpenESB Email BC SMTP Port Configuration

Tags: java, web-services, email, wsdl, esb

To create a SMTP wsdl on NetBeans GlassFish OpenESB 2.3, we can do it easily via the Given User interface to create a concrete WSDL document using Email BC. The Generated WSDL contains

This creates a WSDL with following element that configures SMTP,

```
<email:SMTPaddress emailServer="localhost" useSSL="false" port="1234" userName="noreply" password="password"/>
```

Now, I have tried so many ways to make this port, username, password, email server all configurable. i.e. User inputs them, or say they are somewhere in database, and i want to pull their values from database.

Do you know of a way we can do this in OpenESB?

Comment: Guys, the community of OpenESB is very very limited. Please rate my question so that it gets better visibility..

Answer (score 1):

Did u try using Application Configuration Waqas? Thats the way to go for that.

Comment: i think i tried configurations. its been years now... was this ever resolved?

Comment: Yes, we are using it successfully in production.